# PHP form validation functions not working

Tags: php

I am following a video tutorial series which so far has been great. I am stumped at a part that gives you some form validation functions. The actual form is located here at the moment: http://leegster.com/leegster_test/public/manage_content.php

Here is how the functions are called in create_subject.php:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  // Process the form

  //$menu_name = $_POST["menu_name"];
  $menu_name = mysql_prep($_POST["menu_name"]);
  $position = (int) $_POST["position"];
  $visible = (int) $_POST["visible"];

  // validations
  $required_fields = array("menu_name", "position", "visible");
  validate_presences($required_fields);

  $fields_with_max_lengths = array("menu_name" => 30);
  validate_max_lengths($fields_with_max_lengths);

  if (!empty($errors)) {
      $_SESSION["errors"] = $errors;
      redirect_to("new_subject.php");
  }
```

And here are the functions as shown in validation_functions.php:

```
// * presence
// use trim() so empty spaces don't count
// use === to avoid false positives
// empty() would consider "0" to be empty
function has_presence($value) {
    return isset($value) && value != "";
}

function validate_presences($required_fields) {
    global $errors;
    foreach($required_fields as $field) {
        $value = trim($_POST[$field]);
        if (!has_presence($value)) {
            $errors[$field] = fieldname_as_text($field) . " can't be blank";
        }
    }
}

// * string length
// max length
function has_max_length($value, $max) {
    return strlen($value) <= $max;
}

function validate_max_lengths($fields_with_max_lengths) {
    global $errors;
    // Expects an assoc. array
    foreach($fields_with_max_lengths as $field => $max) {
        $value = trim($_POST[$field]);
        if (!has_max_length($value, $max)) {
            $errors[$field] = fieldname_as_text($field) . " is too long";
        }
    }
}
```

When the form is submitted, validate_presences and validate_max_lengths are called in order to ensure nothing is left blank and that menu_name is no more than 30 characters. The page should refresh and errors should be shown (I can include this code too if needed).

However, when I make a blank entry on the form, it lets me do it. The blank entry is submitted to the database with a success message. I can't understand why this is happening with these new validation functions that are supposed to block that. As far as I can see, I did everything step by step by the video tutorial.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What does `redirect_to()` look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tested your code and it seems that it should work now:

```
function has_presence($value) {
    return isset($value) && $value != ""; // you forgot $, propably a typo
}

function validate_presences($required_fields, $fields) {
    $errors = []; // do not use globals, you should pass all required variables as arguments

    foreach($required_fields as $field) {
        $value = trim($fields[$field]);
        if (!has_presence($value)) {
            $errors[$field] = $field." can't be blank";
        }
    }

    return $errors;
}

function has_max_length($value, $max) {
    return strlen($value) <= $max;
}

function validate_max_lengths($fields_with_max_lengths, $fields) {
    $errors = [];

    // Expects an assoc. array
    foreach($fields_with_max_lengths as $field => $max) {
        $value = trim($fields[$field]);
        if (!has_max_length($value, $max)) {
            $errors[$field] = $field." is too long";
        }
    }

    return $errors;
}

$required_fields = array("menu_name", "position", "visible");
$errors = validate_presences($required_fields, $post);

$fields_with_max_lengths = array("menu_name" => 30);
$errors = array_merge($errors, validate_max_lengths($fields_with_max_lengths, $post));

print_r($errors);
```

However, you should always check for existence of the fields.
This `$value = trim($fields[$field]);` should be changed to:
`$value = isset($fields[$field]) ? trim($fields[$field]) : '';`

Oh, and I don't like this either:
`mysql_prep($_POST["menu_name"]);`
You should definitely escape the post fields first.

Answer (score 0):

simple way to validate a required input form is using html5 required attribute and for limit the char you can use maxlength attribute
example :

```html
<input type="text" name="cat" maxlength="30" required>
```

if you still want to keep using php, you must include a complete contents of the script.
Correct me if im wrong because im newbie too :)

Comment: Thank you for the info. For now, I am just going by the tutorial to see how PHP handles form validation. I understand that it is not the most efficient way to do things usually. I will keep your suggestion in mind! Thanks!